# SSH Java-library for Android?

Tags: java, android, ssh, command

I'm trying to create an app for Android that simply sends a command to an SSH server. No response needed, I just need to be able to send a command. I was wondering if there's any java library out there that I could use?

No advanced stuff needed, just a pure connection to send the command.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are searching for [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

Other libs are [jaramiko](https://github.com/freznicek/jaramiko), [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/), [trilead-ssh2](https://github.com/jenkinsci/trilead-ssh2)  . A place where you can browse the source for trilead is [the connectbot project](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/source/browse/trunk/connectbot#connectbot/src/com/trilead/ssh2). Please notice that connectbot also uses this unmaintained lib.

It also exists a commercial SSH Java lib: [J2SSH Maverick](http://www.sshtools.co.uk/en/j2ssh-maverick/)

Note: Answer refactored due to comment.

Comment: JSch is used builtin in Eclipse, so I guess this is a good, maintained library to use.

Comment: jsch looks good, but it lacks documentation.

Comment: I found documentation at http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html.  You can also generate it yourself by downloading the source code and using javadoc. Finally, you can use the examples at http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/