# Is it possible to integrate QuickSSHd or SSHDroid with my android app?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee

I am developing android apps to connect with j2ee portal for executing interactive shell-scripts remotely..came across a situation like I have to login to Unix/Linux box remotely as well...I have come to know there are such tools like QuickSSHd,SSHDroid allow you to connect with linux/unix servers.. so I just want to know whether its possible to integrate these app with my android App..can anybody suggest me?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268942/ssh-java-library-for-android

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Mr. kirelagin ..just looking at jaramiko libs... i think that can help me out..