# How to create Mqtt Android Client with SSH Tunneling?

Tags: android, ssh, mqtt, ssh-tunnel

I want to connect with my MQTT broker and get some data from Android App.
The Mqtt server has implemented with SSH layer for security reasons.
I want connect Mqtt broker over SSH tunnel. How to achieve this? IS there any opensource library?

Note : I am able to connect by `putty.exe -ssh -L 1883:ipaddress:22 username@ipaddress` and username and password.

Answer (score 1):

If you are limited to SSH you might be able to use the one of the libraries mentioned in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1367997/6581384

Otherwise, If your requirements are flexible, it would be easier to reconfigure the MQTT broker and client to use SSL/TLS instead.